# update global variable inside RatingBarChangeListener

Tags: android

I m not able to get the updated value of `getRate` outside the `onRatingBarChangeListener` to set the text of button with updated value.ex:when `onRatingChange` changes the value of `getRate` to 1 but still after coming out of call back it is showing 0.

```java
    public class RatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ImageView smiley;
        TextView t1;
        TextView smiley_text;
        RatingBar rate;
        Button submit;
        private String getRate;
        private int Submit_Rate;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
            smiley=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_smile);
            t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text_rate);
            smiley_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rate_detail);
            rate=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rate);
            submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Sbmit);

            rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                    getRate=String.valueOf((int) rate.getRating());

                    if(getRate.equals("1")){
                        smiley.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
                        smiley_text.setText(getRate+" star");
                        Submit_Rate=1;
                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(RatingActivity.this,"No Point",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            submit.setText(getRate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never change the Button's text inside the callback. The only time you set the text is at the end of `onCreate`, and that is almost certainly executed before the first execution of the callback.

Comment: ok, but how can i get the updated value of getRate  outside the callback,as i have to use the value inside oncreate method

Comment: You can use `RatingBar`'s `getRating()` method to get the current rating. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but the naming of `String getRate` makes me believe that this an XY problem and the actual underlying problem is based on some kind of misconception.

Comment: i want to getcurrent rating to getRate variable that i got using getRating() but i want to use this variable outside of rate.setonRatin... callback to store it as an integer or an string so that i can use the value to store it inside  firestore.

Comment: I honestly don't see the problem. If you want to change the button's text when the rating changes, you need to call `setText` inside the `OnRatingBarChangedListener`. That's the reason why your Button's text is not updated: you call `setText` before the callback has been executed even once.

Comment: thanx for the help,the problem is solved.